# Learning to use threads that prevent data race conditions

Tags: java, multithreading, race-condition

The following code is supposed to prevent Data Racing by using the synchronized method on common. But for some reason the output is always 19915-19980. Shouldn't it be 20000 if it was not data racing?

```
public class SyncVarDataRace extends Thread {

    private static int common = 0;

    public void run(){
        synchronized((Integer)common){
            int local = common;
            local+=1;
            common = local;
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        SyncVarDataRace[] allThreads = new SyncVarDataRace[20000];

        for(int i = 0; i < allThreads.length; i++){
            allThreads[i] = new SyncVarDataRace();
        }

        for(SyncVarDataRace d: allThreads){
            d.start();
        }

        for(SyncVarDataRace d: allThreads){
            d.join();
        }

        System.out.println(common);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to synchronize on an auto-boxed object that will be a different object every time.

```
synchronized((Integer)common){
```

The whole point is to synchronize on the same object in each thread.  Even if you made `common` be an `Integer`, as soon as you assign it to another value, it would be a different object.

You need to lock on a constant object instead.  I would recommend defining a local Object that you can synchronize on:

```
 private final static Object lock = new Object();
 private static int common = 0;
 ...

 synchronized (lock) {
     common++;
 }
```

It might be better in this specific case, you might consider using an `AtomicInteger`.  That allows you do something like the following without any synchronization.

```
 private static AtomicInteger common = new AtomicInteger(0);
 ...

 // no need to synchronize since that is handled by the class
 common.incrementAndGet();
```