# Why does this thread data race?

Tags: java, multithreading, race-condition

I am new to threads and learning. Why does this data race? I know how to do it using the `Synchronized(){}` method but not with the modifier.

```
public class SyncMethodDataRace extends Thread {

    private static int common = 0;

    public synchronized void run(){
        int local = common;
        local++;
        common = local;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        SyncMethodDataRace[] allThreads = new SyncMethodDataRace[20000];

        for(int i = 0; i < allThreads.length; i++){
            allThreads[i] = new SyncMethodDataRace();
        }

        for(SyncMethodDataRace d: allThreads){
            d.start();
        }

        for(SyncMethodDataRace d: allThreads){
            d.join();
        }

        System.out.println(common);
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Learning to use threads that prevent data race conditions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10309015/learning-to-use-threads-that-prevent-data-race-conditions)

Comment: It's the same issue dude.  You are synchronizing on a different object each time.  This time you are synchronizing on the method which synchronizes on each of the different `SyncMethodDataRace` objects.  You need to synchronize on a single object let I answered your other question.

Comment: When you synchronize the method, it's the same as putting the contents of the method in a `synchronized(this)` block.

Answer (score 3):

By making `run` method `synchronized` you did not achieve the desired synchronization. A synchronized method locks on the current instance of the class. In your example, no other thread is calling the `run` method of another thread, so there is no blocking.

In your case you probably need a static object that is shared among all instances to synchronize on, ie:

```
private static Object syncObject = new Object();

public void run() {
    synchronized (syncObject) {
        //....
    }
}
```